# Why is my Web API controller action not deserializing child properties of child properties?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, frombodyattribute

I'm sending a json payload in a PUT request to a web API controller action.  The action in question has a signature that looks like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]SaveThingRequest request)
```

SaveThingRequest looks something like this:

```
public class SaveThingRequest
{
    public List<ElementInfo> Elements { get; set; }

    public class ElementInfo
    {
        public List<ElementSettingInfo> Settings { get; set; }

        public class ElementSettingInfo
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm posting json in the body of the request that contains Elements that have Settings.  I've confirmed this by manually deserializing in the controller action and confirming that the JSON has a structure that looks something like:

```
{
    Elements: [
        {
            Settings: [
                {
                    Name: 'Name 1',
                    Value: 'Value 1'
                },
                {
                    Name: 'Name 2',
                    Value: 'Value 2'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            Settings: [
                {
                    Name: 'Name 1',
                    Value: 'Value 1'
                },
                {
                    Name: 'Name 2',
                    Value: 'Value 2'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when .NET deserializes the payload and creates the SaveThingRequest, my Elements are populated but all of them have a null Settings property.  I don't know how else to troubleshoot this.  Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be going on here?

Comment: Paste your payload in the question.  Nm, I'm blind.

Comment: I was stuck in the same problem. However, the problem was something else. In my case, the property that was not getting serialized didn't had a default constructor.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This question should be deleted.  It works as advertised.  My problem was that I had an additional property on the JSON called 'settings' (lower-case) that the deserializer was trying to match because NewtonSoft deserialization attempts a non-case sensitive match if a case sensitive one isn't found.  I was able to discover what was happening by changing the signiture of the method to:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string request)
```

and then adding this to the method implementation:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SaveThingRequest>(request);
```

I got a deserialization exception saying:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
> into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Noteable.Contracts.ClinicalReports.SaveThingRequest+ElementInfo+ElementSettingInfo]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object. Path
> 'Elements[0].settings.TextSize', line 11, position 20.

The end of the message showed me what was being deserialized when the deserializer failed and pointed me in the right direction.  =[

Comment: I had a similar scenario where complex object types were not being deserialized appropriately on the webapi request deserializer. I used this solution to debug the issue and correct the serialization process. Yes WebAPI was doing exactly what it should, but it also didnt provide me with a reason or way to address the change specifically that I needed. thanks

Comment: this is a very helpful way to get to the real source of the problem. any idea how to capture the real underlying JSON exception when it occurs?

Comment: This is a very good solution to help you debug your deserializing issues with your web apis.

Comment: The real stackoverflow is when you answer your own question and provide everyone with a valuable debugging method.

Comment: This helped me immensely.  Thanks for this troubleshooting method.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. `object.ToString()` returns `System.Object`. How is this useful when debugging deserialization issues?

Comment: @keeehlan The helpful part is in using the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` call to manually deserialize.  When Web.API does deserialization of action parameters, it makes a lot of assumptions and covers a multitude of sins when doing so and you don't get to see as much of what's going on.  Doing it manually with `DeserializeObject` is much more strict and will give you insight to issues that Web.API deserialization might hide.

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck in the same problem. However, the problem was something else.

In my case, the property that was not getting serialize was declared without public access specifier. I declared it to public, and it ran perfectly fine.

Hope this will help someone who got stuck in this situation. It took me 20 mins to reach this solution.

Comment: Thank you! It would be nice if it gave you some sort of indication!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't do something stupid like I did and sent a partially 'stringified' JSON string from the browser instead of a JSON object.

See the problem? I didn't at first until I tried deserializing it from a string and then I realized that `shippingAddress` itself was a string instead of being an actual JSON object. The rest of the object was proper JSON, but I accidentally serialized the shippingAddress field.

{
  "fspID": 571285,
  "foo": 444,
  "shippingAddress": "{\"countryCode\":\"US\",\"firstName\":\"Test User\",\"lastName\":null,\"address1\":\"1 Main St4\",\"address2\":null,\"company\":null,\"city\":\"San Jose\",\"stateOrProvince\":\"California\",\"stateCd\":\"CA\",\"zipOrPostal\":\"95131\",\"countryName\":\"United States\",\"countryDesc\":\"United States\",\"phone\":null,\"phone2\":null}"
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSON.NET and the attribute `[JsonProperty]` to name a property – make sure you haven't accidentally copy pasted the same property twice and forgotten to update the string value.

```
 [JsonProperty("billingAddress")]
 public Address BillingAddress { get;set; }

 [JsonProperty("billingAddress")]
 public Address ShippingAddress { get;set; }
```

This will throw a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException` that won't actually be visible to you and will screw up the model.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that the child property was null. However the problem was something else.

I had only a getter on the property, once I added a setter as well, then the property was set as expected.